# How do I put in the values for 4 shapes?

Tags: c#, object

How do I put my four shapes into the object array I have created? Using

```
shapeArray[0] = (1,2,3,4)
```

is all i can think to do and this is obviously incorrect...

```
struct Shapes
{
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int xAxis;
    private int yAxis;
}

Shapes[] shapeArray = new Shapes[4];
```

Comment: Why have you created properties when the fields are already public? Why are the fields public? Are you aware of the downsides of mutable structs?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by mutable structs, but yes your right, the fields can be private and the bottom four lines can be removed.

Comment: Well if you make the fields private, you probably *do* want the properties - although it's not clear what `XAxis` would really mean - if it's just a position, just `X` would be clearer. (Alternatively, have a point and a size...)

Comment: I just want to know how I put the values 1,2,3,4 into width height xAxis and Yaxis for my first shape. Im not sure how to do this.

Comment: Well you should almost certainly have a constructor for those four values. But you *really* should think about mutability first. Do you definitely want to be able to change the values after creation? If so, I would suggest making it a class instead of a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a new constructor for your Shape:

```
struct Shape
{
    public Shape(int width, int height, int xAxis, int yAxis)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.xAxis = xAxis;
        this.yAxis = yAxis;
    }

    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int xAxis;
    private int yAxis;

    public int Width { get { return width; } }
    public int Height { get { return height; } }
    public int XAxis { get { return xAxis; } }
    public int YAxis { get { return yAxis; } }
}
```

Then you can use that to create it:

```
Shape[] shapes = new Shape[]{
    new Shape(1, 2, 3, 4),
    new Shape(2, 4, 6, 8),
    new Shape(1, 2, 3, 4),
    new Shape(4, 3, 2, 1)
};
```

Comment: Ah thankyou, I forgot that a constructor has to have the same name as the class.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't create a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208.aspx) for `Shapes` you'll have to set the properties explicitly

```
shapeArray[0] = new Shapes;
shapeArray[0].width = 1; 
shapeArray[0].height = 2;
shapeArray[0].xAxis = 3;
shapeArray[0].yAxis = 4;
```

HOWEVER the proper way to do this (and avoid having a mutable struct) is to privatize the public fields and add a constructor to your struct:

```
public Shapes(int width, int height, int xAxis, int yAxis)
{ 
    this.width = width; 
    this.height = height;
    this.xAxis = xAxis;
    this.yAxis = yAxis;
}
```

Then you would just use

```
shapeArray[0] = new Shapes(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: This doesn't work it was what i tried initially :( for some reason the 'Shapes' comes out as a method and not a struct.

Comment: Are you sure you declared it properly?  Did you inadvertently add a return type like `void`?